# Find the value of $g'(0)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f(1) = 5$ and $f(3) = 11$. If $g(x) = \int_1^3 f(x+t)dt$ then find $g'(0).$

Please explain your answer.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I didn't.

Answer (score 5):

We have  $g(x)=\int_1^3 f(x+t)dt$, then  $g'(x)=f(x+3)-f(x+1)$, hence $g'(0)=f(3)-f(1)=11-5=6$.

Hope this makes the idea clear.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$, then $f$ is continuous on any compact interval $[a,b]$; hence $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$ and by fundamental theorem of calculus $f$ is the derivative of the map $F_{a,b}: \xi \mapsto \int_{t=a}^{\xi}f(t) \colon ]a,b[ \to \Bbb{R}$. But
$$
\int_{t=1}^{3}f(x+t) = \int_{u=x+1}^{x+3}f(u)
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$
by the change of variables theorem,
and by assumption $g(x) = F_{1,3}(x+3) - F_{1,3}(x+1)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$; hence $g$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$ and
$g'(x) = f(x+3) - f(x+1)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$; so $g'(0) = f(3) - f(1) = 6$ by assumption.